# css only - Table overflow with fixed header

Tags: css, css-tables

I am trying to build a table which is scrollable in the x and y directions if the content is bigger than the container. I also want the header to always be visible at the top. I've got the first part working, and the header is always visible at the top, however the header column sizes do not match up with the table table sizes.

I've created this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/xxQQS/1/

I am after a CSS only solution.

EDIT: There seem to be a quite a few people who seem to think that this cannot only be done with CSS. This may be true, however please don't just post to say 'no this can't be done'. If you can explain why this can't be done without CSS I'll accept your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a clone of your table. For the first table, hide all rows except the headers using `visibility: hidden`. Hide the header of the other table using `visibility: hidden`. Place your tables inside divs with overflow properties set as follows:

```
<div style="overflow-x: hidden; width: 400px;">
    <div style="overflow-y: hidden; height: 20px;">
        <table id="head-only">
        </table>
    </div>
    <div style="overflow-y: scroll; height: 100px;">
        <table id="body-only">
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: There's a problem with this solution: If the table overflows horizontally and vertically, you need to scroll horizontally all the way to the right to reach the vertical scroll bar.

Answer (score 0):

May be for this you have to use JS. Check this http://www.tablefixedheader.com/

Answer (score 0):

I too was searching for a solution for sticky headers to use it in my site. Finally found a Jquery plugin that seamlessly does this sticky header part.
https://github.com/jmosbech/StickyTableHeaders

You need not add any CSS, the plugin takes care of it. It clones the table header during scroll. Initialization is pretty simple

```
$('table').stickyTableHeaders();
```

Hope this helps :) As told in other answers, this cannot be achieved purely through CSS I guess.